# SSIS 14 Buffer Issue - The Buffer parameters have already been changed

Tags: memory-leaks, ssis, buffer, oledb

I've a view with 4610889 rows and I am trying load this data to another database using SQL Server Integration Services 2014.

But in first object which is an OLE DB Source I'm getting the follwoing error:

```
 Error: The system reports 85 percent memory load. There are 25769267200 bytes of physical memory with 3619647488 bytes free. There are 4294836224 bytes of virtual memory with 126980096 bytes free. The paging file has 71665074176 bytes with 52717604864 bytes free.
```

I already see that I need to modify the Buffer parameters in Data Flow properties. And I changed to the follwoing values:

- DefaultBufferMaxRows: 10000000
- DefaultBufferSize: 10000000

But I'm still getting the same issue...

Which options/practices I need to make in order to resolve this situation?

I'm working in a Windows Server 2012 with 64bits.

Comment: Could you confirm that you are execute the package in 64 bit mode and also note the amount of memory on the machine you are running it?

Comment: Nevermind about the memory.  That's in the error message.

Comment: @Yes, 64 bit operating system :)

Comment: The os is, yes, but are you running in 32bit mode?  If debugging this would be in project properties. Else look at the dtexec location.

Comment: @MarkWojciechowicz I have the option Run64BitRunTime as true